# How can I access a file from a remote server for a bulk load in my filesystem?

Tags: sql-server

I allow my users to upload files with my AngularJS application. When receiving these files, they're automatically received by my SQL Server database, using a temporal path, accesible for both systems. But now, I have separated my web and database servers, so the second step becomes a problem, as I need to access that temporary file from a different server, where I have located now my SQL Server. If I change that path into the public URL address, it simply tells me that the file doesn't exists. How can I access remotely that file to load it into my database?

I tried to replace my classic "C:\path\more-path\file.txt" by "https://192.168.1.168:8443/files/file.txt" (which exists from database server, as they're both into the same LAN). I tried to include "blob:" before URL as well. I tried also to define a shared drive, E:, for the "files" drawer, and access it through "E:\file.txt". But, in both cases, "No se puede realizar la carga masiva. El archivo 'https://192.168.1.168:8443/files/image.png' no se puede abrir. Código de error del sistema operativo: 123(El nombre de archivo, el nombre de directorio o la sintaxis de la etiqueta del volumen no son correctos.)."

SELECT Bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk 'https://192.168.1.168:8443/files/image.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB

SELECT Bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk 'blob:https://192.168.1.168:8443/files/image.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB

SELECT Bulkcolumn FROM OPENROWSET (Bulk 'E:\image.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB

Instead of selecting the image, I get always the same error.